# When copying bulk values into cell macro is not updating

Tags: excel, vba

Currently using this macro cell template off Microsoft, it works perfectly when I input data into the B column one by one but when I try to copy and paste data into B1:B10 the macro will not run and column A will not update. Also If I wanted the same macro for another range column would I have to make another function exact same and change the `Set KeyCells = Range( : )` or can I add in a conditional statement in the same function?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B1000")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

If Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = "A" Then
   Cells.(Target.Row, 1).Value = "AA"
End If

If Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = "B" Then
   Cells.(Target.Row, 1).Value = "BB"
End If



End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to loop through the cells in target.

Comment: Or (perhaps more robust) loop through the cells in the intersection of `Target` and `KeyCells`. Note: `Range(Target.Address)` is redundant. Just `Target` is enough.

Comment: Im new to vba and excel could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I would enclosed my if statements in a for loop like this and it should work? `For each myCell In KeyCells`

Answer (score 1):

Loop the intersection of the target cells and the desired range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Intersect(Range("B1:B1000"), Target)

    If Not KeyCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In KeyCells
            If rng.Value = "A" Then
               rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "AA"
            ElseIf rng.Value = "B" Then
               rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "BB"
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of using Offset compared to if I just coded it like `Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = "AA`

Comment: Also If im reading the offset correctly, 0 is the reference point and -1 would be a column to the left?

Comment: Not for the small sample size you are using, but for larger yes, it will be quicker.  and  it would be `rng.row` not `target.row` in my code.  Yes `(0,-1)` means same row one cell to the left.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would I adjust the code if I wanted to make changes to another column range? ("C1:C1000") and ("D1:D1000")? Could I just copy this exact function and just change the Range